# Sending a jQuery value to Django view

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I am pretty new in Django and jQuery. I am looking for a way to send some jquery variable to my django views when i click a button.  I have created a button and some jQuery code which can display an alert message with the button's value when clicked,  but i do not know how to send that value to my django views.

Comment: Read up on how to use ajax to send data from page to server and receive whatever you need

Answer (score 0):

jq:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$('#auth-login-form').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/user/login/",
        data:{"username":$("#auth-login-username").val(),"password":$("#auth-login-password").val()},
        beforeSend:function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $.cookie('csrftoken'));
        },
        success:function(data,textStatus){
            alert('success');
        },
        error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

django view:

```
 def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get("username", "")
        password = request.POST.get("password", "")
        return HttpResponse('OK')
    else:
        return render(request, 'user/login.html')
```